# Move element to position after Jquery Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have problems with position my elements after a drop.

I have a "list" with divs...
To make that list "update" and keep the divs together i use jquery `append`for moving the element from the list to it's dropzone.

When i append the element to it's new parent the position of the element will be top-left.
 But of corse i'd like the element to stay in the dropped position.
So i try to save the dropped position, append the element and then move it back to where it was dropped.

But the element want move to the saved dropping position.
I've tried to move it both in `.draggable` and in `.droppable`
The `.drop:` runs first, so there is no problem with empty vars

Check fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0apuqnxd/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class='thisFlak' id='"+flakId+"'>
<div class='flakUp'>Drop here</div>
<div class='flakMiddle'><span class='flakCount'>NO drop</span></div>
<div class='flakDown'>Or here</div>
```

```
<div class="elementsDiv" id="'.$row['element_nr'].'" style="width: 200px; height: 25px; background-color: #c2c2d6; cursor: move">Drag me 1</div>
<div class="elementsDiv" id="'.$row['element_nr'].'" style="width: 150px; height: 35px; background-color: #c2c2d6; cursor: move">Drag me 2</div>
<div class="elementsDiv" id="'.$row['element_nr'].'" style="width: 160px; height: 35px; background-color: #c2c2d6; cursor: move">Drag me 3</div>
```

**JS**

```
//Make elements Draggable
$('.elementsDiv').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: 'clone',
  opacity: '0.7',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    //Move back element to dropped position
    $(draggedElement).css('top', yPos).css('left', xPos);
  }
});

$('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
  accept: '.elementsDiv',
  over: function(event, ui) {},
  drop: function(event, ui) {

  //Get dragged Element (checked)
  draggedElement = $(ui.draggable);

  //Get dropZone where element is dropped (checked)
  dropZone = $(event.target);

  //Move element from list, to dropZone (Change Parent, Checked)
  $(dropZone).append(draggedElement);

  //Get current position of draggable (relative to document)
  var offset = $(ui.helper).offset();
  xPos = offset.left;
  yPos = offset.top;
  $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
  $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);

  //Move back element to dropped position
  $(draggedElement).css('top', yPos).css('left', xPos);

  console.log(draggedElement.position());
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your Javascript code is working but the problem here is that your divs are positioned static, meaning that 'top' and 'left' properties won't work on them.

A good fix is to position them `absolute` at the moment of dropping so they will move to the given values.

Comment: Interesting, i will try this!

Comment: Can you please make an update to my fiddle, with working example?